# Is it possible to run a bitcoind server on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bitcoin

I want to automate some transactions and need to do it within an app on Heroku.

Comment: You want to accept bitcoins as payment?

Comment: Actually, it looks like you can generate bitcoins with bitcoind and I dont think Heroku would want you abusing the service like that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any method for running bitcoind on Heroku but it's probably a moot point anyway. Bitcoind doesn't necessarily have to live on the same system as the code that accesses it. Choose a non-default port and a strong username/password combo in your bitcoin.conf and you can run it anywhere. If you feel like taking it that far there should be an option for SSL.

Comment: Yes. There is an easy way to setup the SSL: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Enabling_SSL_on_original_client_daemon